# Is Interface Builder Really Pixel Accurate?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I often find I need to programmatically nudge GUI elements around programmatically after I lay them out in IB. Can someone please give me the low down on the pixel accuracy of IB?

Adobe Illustrator? Pixel accurate. IB? Hmmm ...

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be as pixel accurate as laying the objects out in code. If you find yourself needing to nudge the items. It may be because the content placed in them is making them a different size.

In the Size Inspector check out the Auto Sizing options. Perhaps you are expecting them to be center aligned when they are actually left aligned.